# How do I get the NSURLResponse before the downloadTaskWithURL finishes?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, nsurlsession

This is my code for download :

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2013/Photoshop_Image_of_the_horse_053857_.jpg")!

let documentsDirectoryURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL

NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
    (location, response, error) -> Void in

    if let error = error {
        println(error.description)
    }
    else {
        println("Finished downloading \"\(response.suggestedFilename)\".")
        println(location.path!)
        println("Started saving \"\(response.suggestedFilename)\".")
        if NSFileManager().moveItemAtURL(location, toURL: documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(response.suggestedFilename!), error: nil) {
            println("File saved")
        } else {
            println("The File \(response.suggestedFilename!) was not saved.")
        }

    }
}).resume()
```

As it is right now, response it is only accessible inside the completion handler.

My question is how to access the response before the download finishes?

I need the NSURLResponse to know:

- expectedContentLength
- suggestedFilename
- MIMEType

Comment: All documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use Shared session

Keep a session property,use this function to init.

```
 init(configuration configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration?,
      delegate delegate: NSURLSessionDelegate?,
 delegateQueue queue: NSOperationQueue?) -> NSURLSession
```

Then use **dataTask** to download image

In this delegate method you can get **Response**

Then change the **dataTask** to **downlaodTask**

```
optional func URLSession(_ session: NSURLSession,
            dataTask dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask,
  didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse,
   completionHandler completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void)
```

Example code:

```
 import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,NSURLSessionDelegate,NSURLSessionDataDelegate,NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate{
    var session:NSURLSession?
    var dataTask:NSURLSessionDataTask?
    let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2013/Photoshop_Image_of_the_horse_053857_.jpg")!
    var infoDic = NSMutableDictionary()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let manqueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate:self, delegateQueue: manqueue)
        dataTask = session?.dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
        dataTask?.resume()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        NSLog("%@",response.description)
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.BecomeDownload)
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didBecomeDownloadTask downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask) {
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
        NSLog("%@",location);
        //Get response
        NSLog("%@", downloadTask.response!.description)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to use a buffer, I want to save it to a tmp file, the buffer uses memory, I want to save it to disk, the same way I was doing it as shown in my code, `DownloadTaskwithurl ` was my question.

Comment: I update the code, in this way you do not need buffer any more

Comment: You can use dataTask to get response then convert data task to DownloadTask. So this is saved to file.And you can get that file in `didFinishDownloadingToURL`

Comment: Just in the same way of your code.The tmp file is located in `location`,you can move it to other path.

Comment: I need to know the response at the completion handler also.to be able to rename the tmp file to the correct file name and extension

Comment: You keep a response property is fine.Quite simple

Comment: there will be multiple downloads going on.if you show me how to do it I will accept your answer..:)

Comment: If doing like this starting with dataTask will it be able to download large files.

Comment: Check the update code,I test it,it works fine.You can get response from `downloadTask.response`, forget what I said before

Comment: `downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename` this will work too.

Comment: @LeoDabus,In my way I use`  completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.BecomeDownload)` to change dataTask to download task.I think the only data in memory is the http response

Comment: @LeoDabus How about using dataTask first,then get the newRequest in willPerformHTTPRedirection. Then cancel the dataTask and start a new download taskWith the newRequest