# Is there a specific order that a URLSessionDataDelegate receives error, response, and data?

Tags: swift

Am using the class below as the delegate for all my URL needs in SwiftUI. Which works fine.

But I wanted to know if there is a specific order which I will receive the functions below in?

Is **response** guarantee to come in before **data**? or vice versa?

```
class MyURL: NSObject, ObservableObject, URLSessionDataDelegate,URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate{
    

    // Error received
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        if let err = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                errMsg = err.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }

    // Response received
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(URLSession.ResponseDisposition.allow)
        
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            xFile?.httpResponse = httpResponse.statusCode

            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                
            }
        }
    }


    // Data received
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        if xFile?.httpResponse == 200 {
            do {
            // run JSON decoder here on received data   
        }
    }
    

    func delayText() async {
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5000000000)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.errMsg = "done"
        }
    }
    
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    }
    
}
```

I can watch in the debugger, but that doesn't mean that will always be the same order.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/30047706/2303865

Comment: What is the reason to prefer old Objective-C based delegate methods over modern `async/await` in SwiftUI?

Comment: @vadian I was integrating an old function into SwiftUI. After your comment I decided to buckle down and learn the new way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `didReceive response` will be called before `didReceive data`.

The whole point of having the `didReceive response` method is to let you decide what to do with the task (to allow it to continue, to cancel it, or to convert it to a download task), when you have only received its headers.

It would not make sense if you make this decision *after* some/all data has been received. If you decided to convert to a download task after some data has already been received, then not all of the data would be downloaded.

We can therefore deduce that `didReceive data` will only be run after you call the `completionHandler` parameter in `didReceive response`.

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1410027-urlsession), it is also said that the headers are the *initial* reply:

> Tells the delegate that the data task received the initial reply (headers) from the server.